# Printing Python Output to Specific Div in HTML

Tags: python, php, html

I've been searching up this for at least a week, with no fruitful results coming up. In particular, the main ways that have come up are creating a django project with a complicated file structure and all, but I simply just want to output some Python strings to a specific div with my existing file structure (a simple one that consists of PHP/HTML files, my Python file, and my CSS/JS folders). Then I found [this result](https://dev.to/vickilanger/print-or-extend-python-output-to-an-html-file-1epm), and the main answer (scroll down a bit, it's by @miniscruff) fortunately doesn't require anything complicated except adding some code. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Is this a problem with PHP (since @vickilanger's file is an HTML file instead of a PHP, and she claims that the code worked)?

My `index.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam&family=Pangolin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.placeholder').load("nav.html?v=<?php echo time(); ?>");
        });
    </script>    

    <code class="language-python match-braces" id="main-num">
        Fetching portfolio...
    </code>
    

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


    <script>
        fetch("test.py")
            .then(response => {
                if(!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Bad Response")
                }
                return response.text()
            })
            .then(text => document.getElementById("main-num").innerText = text)
            .catch(error => document.getElementById("main-num").innerText = error)

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `test.py`:

```py
satisfy = [3, 6, 12, 53, 78, 586]
for num in satisfy:
 if num > 15:
  print(num)
```

Additionally, would there be any other simple way to print Python to HTML if the dev.to method doesn't work?

Comment: Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Another bump here

Comment: Hi! Can you please copy here the error you are receiving?